# Migrate codebase from PHP to Nest JS

Tags: javascript, php, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I want to migrate my old PHP application to Nest Js and for database I want to use TypeORM, the real problem I am facing is my old PHP code uses raw queries for database operations and doesn't have any ORM model. Is there some way so that TypeORM entities can be created automatically without me writing for each table manually as I have a lot of data in tables, I can't afford to lose it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I could help you to migrate to PHP to NestJS

You could use 'DataSource'to use raw sql in typeorm. (version 0.3.0 or  update version)

If you want to use Raw SQL in NestJS check this link. (GitHub Repository)
https://github.com/Alex-Choi0/NestJS_useRawQuery_TypeORM.git

There is a simple query(SELECT).

```
// src/users/users.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectDataSource, InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository, DataSource } from 'typeorm'; // Use DataSource
import { UserEntity } from './entity/user.entity';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(UserEntity)
        private readonly userEntity : Repository<UserEntity>,

        // DataSource : Inject to your constructor
        @InjectDataSource() 
        private dataSource : DataSource,
    ){}

    async getAllUsers(){
        return await this.dataSource.query(`SELECT * FROM users`) // Now You could ues Raw Query
    }
}
```

This is my blog but it was written by Korean
https://engineeringshw.blogspot.com/2022/09/nestjs-raw-sql-typeorm-typeorm030.html

Comment: I even found how to create models automatically, but this project is now under maintenance, so not working for all tables.
```https://github.com/Kononnable/typeorm-model-generator```